# Dsiplaying pre-filled fields in a django form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I am working on an app that needs to send emails to multiple users. Users are picked from a separate admin page, then a newsletter object is created in "send newsletter" action and an HttpResponseRedirect is returned to the admin edit page for the newsletter. What I want to do is instead of having a multiple select list for the recipients (there are too many addresses in the list for it to be of any use) I just want to have a div that lists the selected email addresses for reference, without any ability to edit. How do I do that?

Not sure why this is relevant, but the Newsletter model looks something like this

```
class Newsletter(models.Model):                                                                                                                                                                                     
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+', blank=False)                                                                                                                                                  
    sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)                                                                                                                                                                       
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)                                                                                                                                                          
    date_sent = models.DateTimeField(null=True)                                                                                                                                                                     
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)                                                                                                                                                                      
    content = HTMLField()                                                                                                                                                                                           
    recipients = models.ManyToManyField(Email, related_name='+')                                                                                                                                                    

class Meta:                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    ordering = ['date_sent', 'date_created']
```

There are no views, what I want is to display recipients as non-editable list of email addresses in django admin. I don't want to just disable the widget, since there are too many emails in the Email model, I just want the ones selected for this particular newsletter listed somewhere on the admin edit page.

Comment: please add code for your Newsletter model and any relevant view code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way: a readonly field.

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   readonly_fields = ('_recipients', )
   fields = ('_recipients',)

   def _recipients(self, obj):
     return u', '.join([x.email for x in obj.recipients.all()])
   _recipient
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, I get django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'NewsletterAdmin.fields' refers to field '_recipients' that is missing from the form.

Comment: Just adding recipients as a read-only field worked just like I wanted though.

Comment: What version of django are you using? Specying a readonly field in fields is completely valid since at least 1.3. Otherwise, you'd have no control over where it goes.

Comment: Specifying read-only in fields doesn't cause a problem, but it seems that specifying a method as a field is causing the error. I am using 1.4.

Comment: No, it works on 1.4. Also works on 1.3! Been using it for years. Check this simple example: works in any modeladmin: `readonly_fields = ('_foo',)
    fields = ('_foo',)
    def _foo(self, obj):
        return obj`